# Battery Threshold for Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro with Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: lenovo, battery

I have a Lenovo Yoga 3 pro and I installed an Ubuntu 15.10 on it. Unfortunately I fully deleted Windows.

The battery charging stops at 59%.

[I've read that you can set battery thresholds for ThinkPad with an application called `tlp`](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#battery)

But `tlp` tells me

```
Error: ThinkPad extended battery functions not available.
```

I think because this battery threshold stuff works for ThinkPads only.

Comment: did you get rid of this problem by upgrading?

Comment: for this command: `sudo tlp setcharge BAT0 50` it replies: `Error: ThinkPad extended battery functions not available.`  (I'm using Ubuntu 16.10)

Comment: Ah so the problem persists? :( still looking for answers then I guess